# Python library to amount to word for check

Tags: python

I have checked num2words library but we want amount to word, so we can print on check. 
ex. 23.25 means "Twenty three and 25 cents" in num2words library treat like "Twenty-three point two five"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always extend the existing library :)

```
from num2words import num2words

def amt2words(amount, currency='dollars', change='cents', precision=2):
    change_amt = (amount - int(amount))*pow(10, precision)
    words = '{main_amt} {main_word}'.format(
        main_amt=num2words(int(amount)),
        main_word=currency,
    )
    if change_amt > 0:
        words += ' and {change_amt} {change_word}'.format(
        change_amt=num2words(change_amt),
        change_word=change,
    )
    return words

amt2words(23.25)
# 'twenty-three dollars and twenty-five cents'
amt2words(20)
# 'twenty dollars'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from num2words import num2words

test = 23.25

intpart,decimalpart = int(test), test-int(test) 
print(num2words(intpart).replace('-', ' ') + ' and ' + str( int(decimalpart * (10 ** (len(str(decimalpart)) - 2)))) +  ' cent')
```